# switching between 2 Div's using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to switch between 2 div's if certain condition is met.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(".myImg").click(function(){
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
    $(".showImg").attr("src",imgSrc);
    $( ".borders" ).hide('slow');
    $( ".borderswBadges" ).show('slow');
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
  <img class="myImg" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; float:left;" src="badges/legal1.png" width="54" height="123"/>
  <img class="myImg" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; float:left;" src="badges/legal2.png" width="54" height="123"/>


<div class="badge" id="apDiv2"><img class="showImg" width="73" height="140" /></div>
```

and I am using the following code to hide the Div's using select options `YES/NO`.

html:

```
<select id="test" name="form_select" onchange="showDiv(this)">
   <option value="1">Yes</option>
   <option value ="0">No</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#test").change(function() {

    if ($("#test").val() == 0)
    {
        $(".borders").hide();
            $(".borderswBadges").hide();
    }
    if ($("#test").val() == 1)
    {      
        $(".borders").show();
            $(".borderswBadges").show();
    }
});

    $("#test").change();

});
 </script>
```

Now the question is this... everything works except when I try to choose YES or NO in the test select form, it will either remove both of the Div's `.borders` and `.borderswBadges` or show both of them!!!

what I need to do is to find a way to show one of the other...

For example, IF the `.borders` is showing, I want the `.borderswBadges`to hide and IF  the `.borderswBadges` is showing, I need the `.borders` to hide!

how can i achieve this?

any help would be appreciated .

Comment: where is 'showDiv' and 'myImg'?? Add full code man!

Comment: It's not recommended to query the DOM as generously as you did in your code. Please cache them and reuse for better performance.

Answer (score 2):

its because you show/hide them both. change your if statement to this:

```
if ($("#test").val() == 0)
{
    $(".borders").hide();
        $(".borderswBadges").show();
}
if ($("#test").val() == 1)
{      
    $(".borderswBadges").hide();
        $(".borders").show();
}
```